# python yaml load_all fetching wrong Keys

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

yaml.load all requires space after ":" to recognize the right key. If it does not find the space it will use the whole key value pair as key and then give None as value.

See below: OP print has **'B2_key:B2_VAL': None**

```
test_item = "A1: {B1_key: b1_val, B2_key:B2_VAL}"
yaml_iterator = yaml.load_all(test_item, Loader=yaml.Loader)
op = {}
for item in yaml_iterator:
    op.update(item)
print(op)

Output print: {'A1': {'B1_key': 'b1_val', 'B2_key:B2_VAL': None}}
```

I understand we can just have IP file in the right format. But is there a way we can handle it? i want users to not be care about spaces.

One way can be to inspect the the OP dict and handle it there.

Please advice best way to handle this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *i want users to not be care about spaces.* Then choosing an indentation-based format is a really bad idea. As you said yourself in the comment to an answer, you cannot know whether a user intended a `:` to be a value delimiter or part of the content if you drop the following-space requirement. This is exactly why YAML requires the space. If you know that you cannot distinguish, what kind of answer do you expect?

Answer (score 1):

The [YAML syntax](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html) explicitly states that a colon must be followed by a space. You therefore have two options:

1. Require your users to write in YAML (even if that means they have to add a space after the colon when specifying keys); or,
2. Use a half-thought-out format somewhat resembling YAML, for which you do not have a parser already built, and which does not allow keys with a colon in them.

**Go with option 1**.

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want your users to care about the syntax and you have the yaml in a string, you could add spaces after the semicolons:

```
test_item = test_item.replace(':', ': ')
```

Output:

```
{'A1': {'B1_key': 'b1_val', 'B2_key': 'B2_VAL'}}
```

But this would only work if semicolons are not allowed in the keys and values.

Comment: this is good. But some value can be a string which might have : in it and i might tamper it :(

Comment: In that case I guess you would have to build a custom parser for your specific needs, as Amitai mentioned in his answer.